# 403 error with GET only occurs on lambda deployed

Tags: aws-lambda, https, axios, serverless-framework

if do GET request to

```
https://api-cypress.scope.klaytn.com/v1/tokens/0xc6a2ad8cc6e4a7e08fc37cc5954be07d499e7654/holders?page=1
```

with Postman, browser and serverless local invoke,
I can get response with 200,
But, After I deploy the same code already tested with local invoke,

it gets error like

```
2021-12-31T14:52:16.865Z    44a31e80-7dc0-4696-ad72-3317bac86113    ERROR   Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (/var/task/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/var/task/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/var/task/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:260:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1241:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  config: {
    url: 'https://api-cypress.scope.klaytn.com/v1/tokens/0xc6a2ad8cc6e4a7e08fc37cc5954be07d499e7654/holders',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: '*/*',
      'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
      'accept-language': 'ko-KR,ko;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.1'
    },
    params: { page: 1 },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    data: undefined
  },
  request: ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      socket: [Function],
      abort: [Function],
      aborted: [Function],
      connect: [Function],
      error: [Function],
      timeout: [Function],
      prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    _contentLength: 0,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'api-cypress.scope.klaytn.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 10,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'api-cypress.scope.klaytn.com',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: false,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: false,
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: null,
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular],
      write: [Function: writeAfterFIN],
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 6,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: null,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 266,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 269,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
    },
    connection: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'api-cypress.scope.klaytn.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 10,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'api-cypress.scope.klaytn.com',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: false,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: false,
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: null,
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular],
      write: [Function: writeAfterFIN],
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 6,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: null,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 266,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 269,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
    },
    _header: 'GET /v1/tokens/0xc6a2ad8cc6e4a7e08fc37cc5954be07d499e7654/holders?page=1 HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: */*\r\n' +
      'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\n' +
      'accept-language: ko-KR,ko;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/0.21.1\r\n' +
      'Host: api-cypress.scope.klaytn.com\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      options: [Object],
      requests: {},
      sockets: [Object],
      freeSockets: {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      scheduling: 'fifo',
      maxCachedSessions: 100,
      _sessionCache: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'GET',
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    path: '/v1/tokens/0xc6a2ad8cc6e4a7e08fc37cc5954be07d499e7654/holders?page=1',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: false,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      connection: [TLSSocket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      headers: [Object],
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      trailers: {},
      rawTrailers: [],
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 403,
      statusMessage: 'Forbidden',
      client: [TLSSocket],
      _consuming: false,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular],
      responseUrl: 'https://api-cypress.scope.klaytn.com/v1/tokens/0xc6a2ad8cc6e4a7e08fc37cc5954be07d499e7654/holders?page=1',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'api-cypress.scope.klaytn.com',
    protocol: 'https:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 0,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function],
      _currentRequest: [Circular],
      _currentUrl: 'https://api-cypress.scope.klaytn.com/v1/tokens/0xc6a2ad8cc6e4a7e08fc37cc5954be07d499e7654/holders?page=1',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'accept-encoding': [Array],
      'accept-language': [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    }
  },
  response: {
    status: 403,
    statusText: 'Forbidden',
    headers: {
      server: 'awselb/2.0',
      date: 'Fri, 31 Dec 2021 14:52:16 GMT',
      'content-type': 'text/html',
      'content-length': '118',
      connection: 'close'
    },
    config: {
      url: 'https://api-cypress.scope.klaytn.com/v1/tokens/0xc6a2ad8cc6e4a7e08fc37cc5954be07d499e7654/holders',
      method: 'get',
      headers: [Object],
      params: [Object],
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      data: undefined
    },
    request: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      connection: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'GET /v1/tokens/0xc6a2ad8cc6e4a7e08fc37cc5954be07d499e7654/holders?page=1 HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: */*\r\n' +
        'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\n' +
        'accept-language: ko-KR,ko;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.21.1\r\n' +
        'Host: api-cypress.scope.klaytn.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/v1/tokens/0xc6a2ad8cc6e4a7e08fc37cc5954be07d499e7654/holders?page=1',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'api-cypress.scope.klaytn.com',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    data: '<html>\r\n' +
      '<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>\r\n' +
      '<body>\r\n' +
      '<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>\r\n' +
      '</body>\r\n' +
      '</html>\r\n'
  },
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
```

The code successed with local invoke, but got 403 at aws lambda environment is

```
const url = 'https://api-cypress.scope.klaytn.com/v1/tokens/0xc6a2ad8cc6e4a7e08fc37cc5954be07d499e7654/holders?page=1';

const { data: { total }} = await axios.get(url)
console.log({ total });
```

why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I did not configure the Environment variables that hold my credentials. Have you checked that yet?